# Works with XAML Datatrigger, but not with XAMl MultiDataTrigger.

Tags: wpf, xaml

When using Normal trigger I can get the functionality to work easily.
But when I use MultiDataTrigger I cannot get it to work.

This does not work.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Style x:Key="Brush_GridBackground" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=cb_BackgroundColor, Path=SelectedItem.Tag}" Value="Red" />
                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=cb_BackgroundColor, Path=SelectedItem.Tag}" Value="White" />
                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=cb_BackgroundColor, Path=SelectedItem.Tag}" Value="Black" />
                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=cb_BackgroundColor, Path=SelectedItem.Tag}" Value="Blue" />
                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=cb_BackgroundColor, Path=SelectedItem.Tag}" Value="Green" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ElementName=cb_BackgroundColor, Path=SelectedItem.Tag}" />
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This works

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Style x:Key="Brush_GridBackground" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
    <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cb_BackgroundColor, Path=SelectedItem.Tag}" Value="Red">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ElementName=cb_BackgroundColor, Path=SelectedItem.Tag}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cb_BackgroundColor, Path=SelectedItem.Tag}" Value="White">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ElementName=cb_BackgroundColor, Path=SelectedItem.Tag}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cb_BackgroundColor, Path=SelectedItem.Tag}" Value="Black">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ElementName=cb_BackgroundColor, Path=SelectedItem.Tag}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Howcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `MultiDataTrigger` is like using an `AND` statement with your Triggers, so you are basically saying if the `Tag` is equal to `Red`, `White`, `Black`, `Blue`, and `Green`, then apply the following style, however the tag can only equal to one of those values, so the trigger is always going to end up as False.

Having Multiple triggers, such as your working code, is the syntax I use if I want to `OR` the triggers.

Comment: Ahh okay. I understand. Is it possible to OR commands in XAML?

Comment: as far as I can find, i have to use a converter to do it

Comment: There's no need for an `OR` condition as you can use multiple DataTriggers.